# What command can I run to erase all partitions and create a new one

Tags: linux

Is there a command can I run to erase all partitions that exist, and then create one new one?

Comment: Does overwriting the partition table suffice for you? And what kind of partition table do you need? (msdos, GPT, etc.)

Comment: Yes ideally I'd like to erase all partitions and start over with one new partition. Not sure which table I need. I'm using a chromebook. Messed up my partitions and want to start from scratch. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `fdisk` for old-style non-GPT partition tables - it's the easiest. Follow a how-to like [this one](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-delete-a-partition-with-fdisk-command/).

**Bonus for batch operations or restoring later**

*Just because I already wrote this before the second comment on the question was written.*

For regular non-GPT partition tables I can recommend using `sfdisk` for scripted partition a device. This is also particularly useful for partitioning a batch of similar disks identically.

From the manpage of `sfdisk`:

```
DESCRIPTION
  sfdisk has four (main) uses: list the size of a par‐
  tition, list the partitions on a device,  check  the
  partitions  on  a  device,  and  -  very dangerous -
  repartition a device.

  sfdisk doesn't understand the GUID  Partition  Table
  (GPT) format and it is not designed for large parti‐
  tions.  In these cases use  the  more  advanced  GNU
  parted(8).
```

And use it like this:

1. Dump partition table of `/dev/sda` to `table-sda.sfdisk`

   ```
   sfdisk -d /dev/sda > table-sda.sfdisk
   ```
2. Overwrite (dangerous!) the partition table of `/dev/sdb` using `table-sda.sfdisk`

   ```
   sfdisk /dev/sdb < table-sda.sfdisk
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll check this out later tonight. A colleague of mine mentioned fdisk so I have a feeling this will work. Thanks again!!

Comment: So just to clarify and explain why I'm doing this: I have a chromebook and 'accidently' deleted an important partition, rendering my chromebook semi-useless (i cant every have updates to the OS). 

I'd like to completely erase everything and just make one partition for ubuntu as big as the hard drive allows...Is fdisk the right path I should take? Thanks so much for your help!